# Blending/Combining two semi-complete pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas DataFrames that have similar but incomplete data. It's mostly country-related data, so here's some example of some fake `Population (millions)` data:

**Table A**

```
| Country | 2014 | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 | 2018 |
|--------:|------|------|------|------|------|
| USA     | nan  | nan  | 323  | 325  | 328  |
| UK      | nan  | nan  | nan  | 63   | 65   |
| India   | nan  | nan  | 800  | nan  | 1100 |
| China   | nan  | nan  | 1100 | 1200 | 1300 |
```

**Table B**

```
| Country | 2014 | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 | 2019 |
|--------:|------|------|------|------|------|
| USA     | 319  | 321  | 324  | nan  | 330  |
| UK      | 58   | 60   | nan  | nan  | 68   |
| India   | 780  | 810  | 820  | nan  | 1300 |
| Nigeria | 90   | 100  | 105  | nan  | 110  |
```

From the above, I'm trying to demonstrate a few traits of the datasets I've found:

- Sometimes when two df's have an entry for a value (ex: India 2016) it will be different
- Sometimes some entries are missing from both df's (ex: UK 2016)
- Sometimes rows exist in one table but not the other (ex: Nigeria, China)
- Sometimes columns exist in one table but not the other (ex: 2018 in table A, 2019 in table B)

So I want to combine them such that the `nan`'s are filled up from Table B if they exist, and columns & rows are added if they are not there. If there is a conflict, i don't care which one is used (the differences are not significant enough).

Basically I would like a result to look like this (in this case, Table B vals are used when there is a tie):

**Table A union Table B**

```
| Country | 2014 | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 | 2018 | 2019 |
|--------:|------|------|------|------|------|------|
| USA     | 319  | 321  | 323  | 325  | 328  | 330  |
| UK      | 58   | 60   | nan  | 63   | 65   | 68   |
| India   | 780  | 810  | 820  | nan  | 1100 | 1300 |
| China   | nan  | nan  | 1100 | 1200 | 1300 | nan  |
| Nigeria | 90   | 100  | 105  | nan  | nan  | 110  |
```

*Intuitively, I just want the table as complete as possible*. Is there a way to do this without having to run a for loop? The table is big and I don't want to deal with writing a long loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df_join=( df2.merge(df1,how='outer')
           .groupby('Country')
           .apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
           .drop_duplicates('Country') )
print(df_join)

   Country   2014   2015    2016    2017    2019    2018
0      USA  319.0  321.0   324.0   325.0   330.0   328.0
1       UK   58.0   60.0     NaN    63.0    68.0    65.0
2    India  780.0  810.0   820.0     NaN  1300.0  1100.0
3  Nigeria   90.0  100.0   105.0     NaN   110.0     NaN
7    China    NaN    NaN  1100.0  1200.0     NaN  1300.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `concat` and `groupby`:

```
(pd.concat([df1,df2], sort=False)
   .groupby('Country', sort=False,as_index=False)
   .agg('first')
)
```

Output:

```
   Country   2014   2015    2016    2017    2018    2019
0      USA  319.0  321.0   323.0   325.0   328.0   330.0
1       UK   58.0   60.0     NaN    63.0    65.0    68.0
2    India  780.0  810.0   800.0     NaN  1100.0  1300.0
3    China    NaN    NaN  1100.0  1200.0  1300.0     NaN
4  Nigeria   90.0  100.0   105.0     NaN     NaN   110.0
```

Comment: I've seen answers like that, but what about missing rows from Table A like Nigeria?

Comment: Also, this doesn't solve the problem where Table A has some missing columns too (such as 2019), it only fills up table A.

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees sorry, didn't notice that part. Updated

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
result = pd.concat([A.melt(id_vars='Country', var_name='Year', value_name='Population'),
                    B.melt(id_vars='Country', var_name='Year', value_name='Population')]).dropna()

print(pd.crosstab(index=result.Country, columns=result.Year, values=result.Population, aggfunc='mean'))
```

**Output**

```
Year      2014   2015    2016    2017    2018    2019
Country                                              
China      NaN    NaN  1100.0  1200.0  1300.0     NaN
India    780.0  810.0   810.0     NaN  1100.0  1300.0
Nigeria   90.0  100.0   105.0     NaN     NaN   110.0
UK        58.0   60.0     NaN    63.0    65.0    68.0
USA      319.0  321.0   323.5   325.0   328.0   330.0
```